# Enabling https on Wso2 App Server

Tags: rest, ssl, https, wso2

I have made the REST APIs using Spring MVC framework. The generated WAR file has been deployed on wso2 App server. It is working fine and the REST URI are like `http://domainName:9743/context/api/service.`

Now I want to make these service secure using SSL certificate so that they can be accessed as `https://domainName:9743/context/api/service.`

Please suggest the way how to proceed with that, and how and where I can install the certificate in Wso2 App server. Do I need to make changes in application to make it work over https.

We are using latest wso2 app server version 5.1.0

Thanks
Shakshi

Answer (score 3):

You can access both http and https rest APIs without any change with WSO2 Application Server. But the default http port is 9763, and https port is 9443. So, you need to change these properly.

For ex. in you case, the rest urls will look like the following.

```
http://domainName:9763/context/api/service

https://domainName:9443/context/api/service
```

This is possible because WSO2 AS ships with a self-signed certificate by default. You can [add your own certifacate to AS](http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2012/08/install-your-own-certificate-esb) or you can [add a CA-signed certificate](http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products).

Further HTTP/HTTPS security can be configured as described at [Adding HTTP/HTTPS Channel Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-requires-channel). http, https port mappings etc. will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this easily by using the WSO2 ESB... Please refer the doc http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Securing+REST+APIs  ...

For more OAuth based security refer this : http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/tag/how-easily-engage-the-security-for-rest-services-with-wso2-esb/

Thanks,

Mohan